# What's wrong with my scala.swing?

Tags: swing, scala

I've tried to use `scala.swing` package, but it can't be found. The compiler (2.9.1) says "`swing` is not a member of `scala`". Any ideas? Everything else seems working Ok, I haven't experienced any problems with other Scala packages.

Comment: Have you included `swing` as a dependency?

Comment: No. Isn't it a part of the standard library? Isn't everything under `scala` namespace always included by default?

Comment: If not, then what exactly am I to add to my project dependencies?

Comment: in lib/ directory in the place where your Scala distribution is installed you should have scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, some other jars and scala-swing.jar. Check it and maybe check your paths.

Comment: Not quite sure, but last time I've developed swing app under scala I added dependency as `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.0-1"`. Somebody could clarify, if swing part of scala standart lib or not.

Comment: @s-kucherenko `scala-swing.jar` is present alongside `scala-library.jar`, `scala-compiler.jar`, etc.

Comment: Adding the dependency as @om-nom-nom suggested has solved the problem. It compiles now. But my IDE (IntelliJ Idea 11) still paints it red... :-(

Comment: @Ivan have you invoked `gen-idea`?

Comment: Now I've done it and it has solved the problem.

Comment: Post the answer, @om-nom-nom, I am going to accept it. Despite the fact it's weird (need to include a part of the Scala standard library (included with every Scala distribution) as an external dependency seems absolutely illogical to me).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, to wrap up the solution.
First of all you need to define dependency on `swing` library. Add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.0-1"
```

If you're using Intellij IDEA, with [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin, invoke `gen-idea` to rebuild project to let IDEA know about swing.

Comment: "2.9.1" instead of "2.9.0-1" in my case.

Comment: You can use `scalaVersion.value` instead of hard-coding a Scala version here.